# What is the difference between the dialogs "Network" and "Network Connections"?

Tags: linux, gnome3

I have attached a screenshot of the options available and would like to understand what the differences are. Is there any reason why you would use one over the other apart from a simpler interface for one compared to the other?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both manage the same settings.

The "*Network Connections*" window is `nm-connection-editor`, part of Network Manager. It was the primary way of editing connections in GNOME 2. It will eventually go away.

The "*Network*" window is part of the GNOME 3 "System settings" app (`gnome-control-center`). It is better integrated with GNOME 3 and has such toggles as "Airplane mode" or the "Network proxy" section. On the other hand, it still lacks some features – for example, when you click "Configure", it still automatically runs `nm-connection-editor`.

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean the settings for a given wireless connection has to use `nm-connection-editor` regardless of whether I am using Gnome 2 or 3 or at least Network is better integrated with Gnome 3?

Comment: What do you mean by 'better integrated with Gnome 3'?